# having an issue with php dropdown menus

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm working on a project that requires users to select from a dropdown menu. Using the following code I can only manage to get slots 1 & 2 to display a value. It is currently inserting the other slots as a value of 0 so they are working, just not displaying any values. If this isn't clear enough please let me know and I can try to provide more information. The code is as follows;

```
 echo' <br/>
 Slot 1 
<select name="slot1">';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) and $i<10)
{
echo"<option value='";
echo$row['playerID'];    // sorry about this inverted commas are trickys
echo"'>";
echo $row['name'];
echo "</option>";

$i=$i+1;
}

echo '</select>';

echo' <br/>
Slot 2 
<select name="slot2">';
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) and $i<10)
{
echo"<option value='";
echo$row['playerID'];    // sorry about this inverted commas are trickys
echo"'>";
echo $row['name'];
echo "</option>";

 $i=$i+1;
 }

echo '</select>';

echo' <br/>
Slot 3 
<select name="slot3">';

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) and $i<10)
 {
  echo"<option value='";
 echo$row['playerID'];    // sorry about this inverted commas are trickys
 echo"'>";
 echo $row['name'];
 echo "</option>";

 $i=$i+1;
 }

 echo '</select>';

 echo' <br/>
 Slot 4 
 <select name="slot4">';

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) and $i<10)
 {
 echo"<option value='";
 echo$row['playerID'];    // sorry about this inverted commas are trickys
 echo"'>";
 echo $row['name'];
 echo "</option>";

$i=$i+1;
}

echo '</select>';

echo' <br/>
Slot 5 
<select name="slot5">';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) and $i<10)
{
echo"<option value='";
echo$row['playerID'];    // sorry about this inverted commas are trickys
echo"'>";
echo $row['name'];
echo "</option>";

$i=$i+1;
}

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: shouldn't you be resetting the `$i` back to `0` or `1`?

Comment: When I was setting it to '0' or '1' each time none of the slots would work except the first one

Comment: as a side note, clean up your code, use something like `"<option value='{$row['playerID']}'>{$row['name']}</option>"` it's cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the $i value to 1 before others slot:

```
$i=1;
```

Or you have to think again about how you fill the slot, is it the same query ? Do wan the same values for each slot? In this case you need:
[mysqldataseek](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

Answer (score 0):

An easier way of doing this is would be to gather the html code into variables and later use them in the html section.

```
<?php 

    $slot1 = '';                                                //initializing the slot variables
    $slot2 = '';
    $slot3 = '';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $playerId = $row['playerId'];
        $name     = $row['name'];
        if($i < 10){
            $slot1 .="<option value='$playerId'>$name</option>";        //appending the options using .=
            $i++;
        }
        if($i < 20){
            $slot2 .="<option value='$playerId'>$name</option>";
            $i++;
        }
        if($i < 30){
            $slot3 .="<option value='$playerId'>$name</option>";
            $i++;
        }
    }

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <select name="slot1" >
            <?php echo $slot1 ?>
        </select>

        <select name="slot2" >
            <?php echo $slot2 ?>
        </select>

        <select name="slot3" >
            <?php echo $slot3 ?>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```